# Verification that $\int x\sin x=\sin x- x\cos x + C$ by differentiating both sides of the equation

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

The original question is:

Confirm that the formulae stated below are correct by differentiating both sides:

$\int x\sin x=\sin x-x\cos x+C$

Where does the cancellation occur, and what is the intuition behind it?

Comment: Your title is very different to your question.  Can you differentiate $\sin(x)-x\cos(x)+C$ ?

Comment: You simply need to derive both sides and see that they are equal. Where is the problem?

Comment: Hi, Ray, I upvoted your [question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/267317/why-does-the-nuclear-force-become-stronger-with-distance) because I think the practice of excessive downvoting of duplicates is unfair. Very often they are not duplicates, and sometimes they get better answer than the originals. [My question here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/270050/energy-of-tides-how-does-the-change-of-spin-of-a-body-affect-another-body-throu) for example is not a duplicate since it asks for a better explanation, and yet it got 8 downvotes. Isn't it a shame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have to just check your formula just take derivative on both sides

The right hand side becomes:
$$\frac{d}{dx}(\sin(x)+x\cos(x)+C)$$ $$=\frac{d}{dx}(\sin(x))+\frac{d}{dx}(x\cos(x))+\frac{d}{dx}(C)$$ $$=\cos(x)-[\cos(x)-x\sin(x)]+0$$$$=\cos(x)-\cos(x)+x\sin(x)$$$$=x\sin(x)$$ Now since on the left hand side we have the integral the left hand side becomes:
$$\frac{d}{dx}\int x\sin(x)$$ Now since we know that integration is just the reverse of difffernetiation this becomes- $$x\sin(x)$$
And since the **LHS=RHS** your above formula is true.